# Call spill range within dynamic array formula

Tags: excel, dynamic-arrays, spill-range

I am trying to query a list of sales stored in Excel using a dynamic array formula referencing a spill range and this does not work.

Here is the context:

- I have a table `tabSales` containing the sales, with the following data : date, customer, amount, year (calculated using `=YEAR([Date]`)
- I want to display on another sheet the amount sold year by year for a given customer to be selected by the user in cell B1 (named `SelCust`)

Here is what I have tried on the report sheet:

- I have used the UNIQUE and FILTER functions to make the report display on column D the years where the selected customer has actually bought something : `=UNIQUE(FILTER(tabSales[Year],tabSales[Customer]=SelCust))` (formula input in cell D2)
- I have then tried to use the SUM and FILTER functions and Excel's spill range feature to calculate for each year the total amount sold to the selected customer : `=SUM(FILTER(tabSales[Amount],(tabSales[Year]=D2#)*(tabSales[Customer]=SelCust)))` (formula input in E2)

Unfortunately, this last formula unfortunately does not work:

- Excel returns #N/A in E2
- Cell E2 does not spill over E3, E4, ...

The lack of spilling makes me wonder whether the spill range reference within the FILTER  function is recognized...

How could I get this formula to work ?

[Sales table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NJFsB.png)
[Non-working formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MckMi.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use SUMIFS():

```
=SUMIFS(tabSales[Amount],tabSales[Year],D2#,tabSales[Customer],SelCust)
```

This should return an array properly.

If one wants to do both columns in one dynamic formula we can use LET and CHOOSE:

```
=let(
    slcust,tabSales[Customer],
    amt,tabSales[Amount],
    yr,tabSales[Year],
    unYr,UNIQUE(FILTER(yr,slcust=SelCust)),
    sm,SUMIFS(amt,yr,unyr,slcust,SelCust),
    Choose({1,2},unyr,sm))
```

Comment: Thanks Scott, this is working just fine!  I am now struggling to do the same with TEXTJOIN instead of SUM (the goal would be to merge names of all customers who ordered something over a given year). Do you have any clue on how to achieve that?

Comment: That is a new question. If this worked for this question please mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer. New questions get new posts

Comment: Alright. Being new on this site, I need to learn the customs :-)